# How to force Chrome to always open as application without command line or shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

How are you?

I hope you are safe and sound.

I was wondering how can edit the Windows 10 in order to make chrome/edge to always open always open as the following flags:--app and -userdatadir=C:/temp

Don't want via shortcut or command line.

Thanks.

Comment: Your description seems confusing. Do you mean you want to know about the Windows 10 setting that can open the flags:--app and -userdatadir=C:/temp page when you launch the Chrome or Edge browser? Can you please provide more information about your requirement? It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: In the windows registry we add some flags to chrome right? I would like to add the app and userdatadir there. So chrome will always open like that. I don't want this behaviour with command like, I would like via registry.https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md

Comment: Do the ways provided in my answer help you to set the User Data Directory? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

From your previous comment, I understand that you want to set the User Data Directory using the registry key for the MS Edge Chromium browser.

Here, I am showing you 2 approaches. Using registry key and using group policy.

Below are the steps to set the User Data Directory using the registry key.

1. Open Registry editor.
2. Browse to the location below.

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge

3. Create a new string value and name it as **UserDataDir**.
4. Doubble click on it and set the directory value.
5. Close the Registry editor and relaunch the MS Edge browser.

Below are the steps to set the User Data Directory using the Group policy.

1. Open Local group policy editor.
2. Browse to the location below.

> Computer configuration -> Administrative templates -> Microsoft Edge

3. Find and double click on **Set the user data directory** policy.
4. Click on enabled option and then set the desire value.
5. Close the Local group policy editor and relaunch the MS Edge browser.

Reference:

[Create Microsoft Edge user data directory variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-learnmore-create-user-directory-vars)